# Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar is not showing Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to add materiel design in my project. Whan I try to apply new theme I am facing some problem. Action bar is hided when I apply this theme to my activity.

Style:

```
<style name="MaterialBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/GreenActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupMenuTextAppearance</item>
    </style>
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Summary"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/summary"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/MaterialBaseTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Class:

```
public class Summary extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.route_summary);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // parseView();
       // updateUI();
    }
}
```

Here Action bar is hided for this activity.

When I try to extend `AppCompatActivity` in class I am getting flowing error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.coc.Summary}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
```

Please let me any idea to resolve my problem.

Comment: What is the superclass of BaseActivity? Also, have you tried removing all the elements from your MaterialBaseTheme and seeing whther that makes a difference?

Comment: BaseActivity extends Activity. BaseActivity is my base class. I extend that class to all derived class. Yes, I removed all the elements from my MeterialBaseTheme. Nothing happen.

Comment: BaseActivity will need to extend AppCompatActivity if using an AppCompat theme. Is it still the case there is no Action bar if BaseActivity extends AppComlatActivity and all elements are removed from your theme?

Comment: If I extend `AppCompatActivity` I am getting error. Error message is I already mention in the question.

Comment: How about moving `setContentView()` to after the super call too?

Comment: Yes.. Moving setContentView() to after the super call app is working Without crash. But still Action bar is not showing. I am trying another source too. I will let you know after that..

Answer (score 0):

Please add other styles for theme

```
<style name="MaterialBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/**GreenActionBar**</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/**PopupMenu**</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/**DropDownListView**</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/**PopupMenuTextAppearance**</item>
</style>
```

use this

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity